# Change not being triggered on page load

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a page that I use to create production records for unique line, shift, and date combinations, as well as edit existing records.  I have two drop downs for the line and shift, and a `jQuery` date picker for the date.  When the line changes, the date picker gets disabled and the shift drop down gets reset.  I want to disable the date picker when creating a new shift (enabled after a shift is picked), but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.  Here's my `jQuery` code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                
       $('#lineSel').on('change',function() {
           $('#shiftSel').find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
           $('#datePicker').val('').datepicker('disable');
           console.log('Datepicker disabled');
       });

       $('#shiftSel').on('change',function() {
           $.ajax({
               url: '/api/Shifts/GetDates',
               data: { plantCd: '@Model.PlantCd',
                       lineId: $('#lineSel').val(),
                       shift: $('#shiftSel').val()
                    },
               success: function(e) {
                   var dates = e.toString().split(',');
                   $('#datePicker').datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', function(date) {
                        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                        return [dates.indexOf(string) == -1];
                   });
               }
            });
           $('#datePicker').datepicker('enable');
       });

       if ('@Model.Title' !== 'New Shift') {
           $('#shiftSel').change();
       }     

       $('#lineSel').change();
});
```

`#lineSel` is the drop down for the line, `#shiftSel` the drop down for the shift, and `#datePicker` the date picker.

After the page loads, if I change the line drop down, the date picker disables like it should.  However, `$('#lineSel').change();` executes the `on('change')` code (`'Datepicker disabled'` shows up in browser dev tools console), but the the date picker does not get disabled.

I've tried calling `$('#datePicker').datepicker('disable')` in the `ready` function, adding `.change()` to the end of the event handler binding, using `.change(function()` instead of `on('change', function())`, and other suggestions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022732/firing-a-jquery-change-function-at-document-ready) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984598/jquery-execute-onchange-event-on-onload).

Any ideas why the date picker doesn't get disabled on page load and what I can do fix it?  Using `jQuery UI 1.11.2` in and `ASP.NET MVC 5` application.

Comment: I think a snippet/[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/) well be better to let us test the code .. you can avoid ajax on demo if it not caused for any problems

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/xpz6h12h/, the datepicker input box strangely disabled after page load if `Model.Title` contains `New Shift`. Feel free providing further details to create a repro in MVC view.

Comment: My fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cQaQjQ.  This is my first time doing a fiddle, couldn't get the date picker working (probably something obvious like missing a reference), but it's a simplified version of my code.  @TetsuyaYamamoto, looks like your fiddle has the same behavior as my code, any ideas?

Comment: @user3517375 I ran your fiddle & found `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` in browser console. The datepicker doesn't react at all, even when changing Shift DDL (and `console.log('Datepicker disabled')` not executing too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with @TetsuyaYamamoto's fiddle and trying different things, finally figured out how to get it working.  Replaced `$('#lineSel').change()` with `$('#datePicker').prop('disabled', true)` and that did the trick.  Thanks for the help.